# Tableau - Related Data Source Filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have data split between two different tables, at different levels of detail. The first table has transaction data that, in the fomrat:

```
category item  spend
      a     1    10
      a     2    5
      a     3    10
      b     1    15
      b     2    10
```

The second table is a budget by `category` in the format

```
category limit
      a    40
      b    30
```

I want to show three BANs, `Total Spend`, `Total Limit`, and `Total Limit - Spend`, and be able to filter by category across the related data source (transaction is related to budget table by `category`). However, I can't seem to  get the filter / relationship right. That is, if I use `category` as a filter from the transaction table and set it to filter all using related data source, it doesn't filter the `Total Limit` amount. Using 2018.1, fyi.

Comment: Did you able to find the solution ? I am stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have data split across 2 tables they can be joined using the category field and available as a single data source. You would be then be able to use category as a quick filter.